# Hosting a Website using 1&1 Service

Tags: web-hosting

I'm currently trying to upload a html+css page to my hosting service (1&1 internet).
Unfortunately, I have very little experience in that; and would like to ask this question:

How is it possible to update the existing homepage on a site that already has been uploaded to the web?

I'm using WebspaceExplorer. Now, when I enter it, (Hosting section) there are a lot of folders and files with a few options like download, delete and so on. 
I can't seem to find out how to make the program understand which one should be the homepage.  This is because I see that the page I uploaded is online and accessible, but is not the first page the user sees! How can I change it?

It may be confusing because of the poor description so here is the url of both:
velten-berlin.org (current Homepage)
velten-berlin.org/Upload (desired homepage)

Comment: Webservers serve content located at file paths. These map directly to the path in the URL. If no file name is specified in the URL, the webserver responds with the *index.html* file in that path if it exists. So *velten-berlin.org/Upload* serves *velten-berlin.org/Upload/index.html*. The homepage serves the *index.html* file in the "root" directory of the website. To change the homepage, you need to swap the *index.html* file.

Comment: Could you suggest how do I do that?